# Why did Duryodhan try to imprison Krishna ? Wasn't he aware of power of Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, duryodhana

Krishna had killed Shishupal using Sudharshan Chakra infront of Duryodhna. Despite knowing the capability of Krishna , why did Duryodhan plan to shackle Krishna ? Didn't he fear that Krishna can use Sudarshan Chakra on him ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did people in Krishna's time know that he was God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/did-people-in-krishnas-time-know-that-he-was-god)