# Ashwathama and Swaminarayan

Tags: puranas, vishnu

What is the story of **Ashwathama** cursing Parents of **Lord Swaminarayana**?

I read it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durvasa#Durvasa_.26_Swaminarayan). But I would like to know what is the source of this story? Which Hindu scripture describes this incident?

Comment: If you're interested in Swaminarayan, you may be interested in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10174/36

Comment: I think no authentic Hindu scriptures mention this as this event happened relatively recently.

Comment: Yes, there are authentic scriptures, but how can you expect all the details about the event in the scriptures that is written by ved vyas. In the purans Vyas has written history, and have mentioned few places about the Swaminarayan which I have mentioned here:  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8009/is-swaminarayan-an-incarnation-of-any-god/8884#8884

Answer (score 1):

You can read it in Scripture: Shree Haricharitramrut Sagar, it is in hindi. Shree Haricharitramrut Sagar is the scripture mentioned life events (lila) of Bhagavan Swaminarayan. There are many, but this is the only one I found in hindi.

You can read over here: https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Swaminarayan_Saint_Sadguru_Shree_Adharanandswami_S?id=7ZERAgAAQBAJ.

If you read Pur 1, Tarang 31 to 35. it has all the details you need. Page number 115 to 130. Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Nixit.