# In which section of the Brahmanda Purana, is the advent of Swaminarayan supposedly predicted?

Tags: avatars, identification-request, brahmanda-purana, swaminarayan

Some members of the Swaminarayan sect often quote the following verse supposedly from the Brahmanda Purana to prove Sahajanand Swami (more commonly known as Swaminarayan) to be an incarnation of Sri Hari:

> In Satyayuga, I will take birth as Dattatreya, In Tretayuga, I will be Rama, In Dwapara I will be Krishna and **in Kaliyuga, I will be the son of Vrush (Vrushatmaj) - Hariprasad Pande and will be known as Swaminarayan.**

Now which section of the Brahmanda Purana is this located?

Comment: Every Religious men who lived and formed a Diffearent philosophy and earned popularity is Regarded as an incartion.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda The philosophy of Swaminarayan is not different from Ramanuja.

Comment: "Hariprasad Pande" is Hindi.  Is Brahmanda Purana in Hindi?

Comment: @SK Its just translated that way.

Comment: You have must read this answer because in below alsar beautiful images and mentioned all proof if you need deep knowledge. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8884