# Were Nara-Narayana cursed by Sage Durvasa?

Tags: avatars, identification-request, skanda-purana, curse, durvasa

According to the adherents of the Swaminarayana sect, Nara-Narayana, the twin-pair avatara of Lord Vishnu, were cursed by Sage Durvasa which supposedly led Nara-Narayana to incarnate as [Sahajanand Swami](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan), the founder of the Swaminarayana sect (a subsect in Sri Vaishnavism). [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan_(spiritual_tradition)) says the following about the particular story:

> Followers of Swaminarayan believe that it was events that took place at Badarikashram, the abode of Nara Narayana, that led to the incarnation of Swaminarayan. It is believed that Narayana took birth as Swaminarayan due to a curse of sage Durvasa Muni which he accepted at his own will. The curse led to Narayana taking the form of an avatar on Earth to destroy evil and establish ekantik-dharma, religion based on morality, knowledge, detachment and devotion.[13] Important Hindu scriptures such as the Bhagavad Gita and Bhagavata Purana confirm that Narayana descends in human form to destroy evil though there is no direct reference to Swaminarayan. He was a human & then a sage or philosopher. Only the Swaminarayan followers specifically interpret the Visvaksena Samhita, 11th part of the Brahma Purana, as well as the Skanda Purana as giving a direct reference to Narayana taking birth in the form of Swaminarayan

As you can see, the adherents of this sect cite Brahma Purana and Skanda Purana to prove their point. Can anybody provide me the verse from the Skanda Purana that supposedly hints towards the advent of [Sahajanand Swami](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan)? Does Skanda Purana specifically talk about Sage Durvasa cursing Nara-Narayana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verse occurs in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/GPWA) from the Vasudeva Mahatmya of the Skanda Purana:

> By becoming Buddha, I shall delude by the use of fallacious reasoning and deceit the Asuras who adopting Vedic practices will harass the three worlds.
>
> When the Asuras killed by me as Krishna and by Arjuna in the battles, will promote and establish Adharma (unrighteous practices) on the earth, I, sage Narayana, shall be born on the earth from my devotee Dharmadeva in the land of Koshala, as a Brahmana singer of Saman hymns. O Aja (Brahma), establishing the boly Dharma I shall be the protector of sages who will be born as men by **the curse of Munis** (other sages) as well as Uddhava, O child.
>
> At the end of Kali I shall incarnate as Kalki. Riding a divine horse, I shall kill highly sinful people of Mleccha origin.

It doesn't mention Durvasa by name, it just says "the curse of Munis".  In any case, the Swaminarayan sect interprets this as a prophecy of Swaminarayan.  I posted a question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6623/36) to see how other sects interpret it.

Comment: It will be useful to see the Sanskrit script here. It is not clear if the curse was to the sages who were protected, or to the protecter himself.