# What scriptures describe Krishna's lover Nappinnai?

Tags: krishna, sri-vaishnava, alwar, radha

Most people know about Radha, who is said to be Krishna's lover and his favorite among the Gopis, whom Krishna spent time with during his childhood in Vrindavan and Gokulam.  She's revered by many Vaishnavas, particularly those of the Gaudiya and Nimbarka Sampradayams.  Yet the Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam (of which I'm a member) doesn't emphasize Radha.  In part that's because Sri Vaishnavas focus on the Vishnu Purana and the Srimad Bhagavatam, neither of which even mention Radha's name. Yet Sri Vaishnavas do recognize a figure similar to Radha.  Let me explain.

The Alwars (also spelled Azhwars) are a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who lived in Tamil Nadu and are famous for their poetry in praise of Vishnu. The collection of their 4000 poems, known as the Naalayira Divya Prabhandam, is considered by many to be the "Dravida Veda", or South Indian Veda. The Alwars are crucially important figures in the history of Vaishnavism; it is the beliefs and principles embodied in the Alwars' poems that ultimately gave rise to the Sri Vaishnava sect.

In any case, the Alwars discuss a figure named Nappinnai, daughter of Yashoda's brother Kumbagan.  It is said that Krishna married Nappinai after  defeating the seven bulls of Kumbagan.  Sri Vaishnavas believe that Nappinnai is an incarnation of Vishnu's wife Nila Devi.  Most people only know about Vishnu's wives Sri Devi, aka Lakshmi, and Bhu Devi, aka Bhumidevi, but according to Sri Vaishnavism Vishnu has a third wife named Niladevi; the Nila Sukta of the Yajur Veda is addressed to her:

> O thou of the three-and-thirtyfold Stoma, lady of the world,
>   Breathed on by Vivasvant, do thou be gracious to us;
>   Rich in ghee, O Savitr, through thy overlordship,
>   Be the bounteous region rich in milk, for us.
>   The firm among the quarters, lady of Visnu, the mild,
>   Ruling over this strength, the desirable,
>   Brhaspati, Matarisvan, Vayu,
>   The winds blowing together be gracious to us.
>   Prop of the sky, supporter of the earth,
>   Ruling this world, lady of Visnu,
>   All-extending, seeking food, with prosperity,
>   May Aditi be auspicious to us in her life.

In any case, my question is, apart from the Alwars' poems, are there any scriptures which discuss the story of Nappinnai?

Now [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/58/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam describes how Krishna wins the hand of his queen Satya after defeating the seven bulls of Satya's father king Nagnajit (not to be confused with [this king Nagnajit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7415/36)).  This is exactly how Krishna won the hand of Nappinnai.  So does this have some relation to the story of Napinnai?

Also, I've heard that Yashoda's brother Kumbagan is mentioned in the Harivamsa.  Does anyone know if that's correct?

Comment: Why just "his favorite among the Gopis during his childhood"? She was his "for all times" favorite, literally! :) You have the Harivamsa at http://mahabharata-resources.org/

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I just meant that the Gopis were figures in Krishna's childhood.  I edited the sentence to clarify.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am really interested in answers to many questions you asked on alwars and other tamil saints. It looks like , alwars are not really well known beyond tamilnadu . Probably it is because , apart from one rest of the alwars are born in kali yuga and hence they were not really covered in puranas . Tamil literature which covers them never got really popularized outside state. Tamil kings/saints before kaliyuga are very well covered.For ex: In Gajendra moksha , they clearly mention that , gajendra was tamil pandyan king called indradyumna(Not sure his tamil name).

Comment: Also possible that , they would have used tamil equivalent names for sanskrit names .

Comment: @sysinit First of all, the first four Alwars are said to have been born in the Dwapara Yuga; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6867/36 Second of all, Gajendra Moksham happened all the way back in the Tamasa Manvantara; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6608/36. That's such a long time ago that it was a different world back then.  So who knows what they were speaking in South India?  Tamil is certainly a divine language, but who knows who was speaking what back then?  We know very little about the Tamasa Manvantara.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the Harivamsa Southern Recension contains a chapter 'Krsnasya Nilaya Saha Vivahah', or the marriage of Krsna with Nila Devi. This chapter **exactly** tallies with the account of the Azhvars.

It states that Yashoda had a younger brother called Kumbhaka, who was famous for his piety. He had a wife called Dharmada, who true to her name, was a generous lady, and used to help everyone. They had a son, **Shridama**, and a daughter, **Nila**. They lived near Mithila, the kingdom of (the present) Janaka Maharaja.

The chapter goes on to describe how beautiful Nila was, how no one could equal her in all the worlds, the usual stuff.

Then it says,

> एतस्मिन्नेव काले तु वृषरूपा महासुराः  ।
>   कालनेमिसुताः सप्त विक्रान्ता बाहुशालिनः  ॥  १२अ-१४
>
> Which means, in this time, the seven sons of Kalanemi, who took the forms of terrifying bulls... (after fighting and losing to Vishnu, who then appeared in the Yadava dynasty)...
>
> वृषरूपधराः सप्त कुम्भकस्य व्रजे वसन्  ।
>   बलवन्तो महाशृङ्गा महाकुक्षिशिरोधराः  ॥  १२अ-१७
>
> came to hasten his death in the form of seven mighty bulls, living in the pastures of Chief Kumbhaka.

These bulls caused havoc, and Janaka told Kumbhaka to do something else he would be punished. Kumbhaka proclaimed,

> तप्तानां  वृषमल्लानां दमिता यो भवेद्भुवि  ।
>   तस्मै कन्यां प्रदास्यामि नीलां नीरदलोचनाम्  ॥  १२अ-३४
>
> I will give my lotus eyed daughter Nila to the man who can control these seven ferocious bulls.

Then, Nandagopa arrives along with Rama and Krsna to Kumbhaka's village. The bulls, in the night, slaughter the calves and their protectors (come on!). Some more gopas die. Then Krsna enters (finally). He tells Balarama the history of the bulls and says, Vayam Etair Yatha Yogam Kreedam Kurmah, viz. "We shall play with these bulls however the time and situation permits!"

Then Krsna enters the arena, and with his powerful fists, sens each bull to Yamaloka one by one.

> क्रमेण मुष्ट्या  तान्सर्वान्हत्वा दैतेयगोपतीन्  ।
>   नीलां हस्ते  गृहीत्वाथ  कृष्णस्तस्मिन्व्यरोचत  ॥  १२द्-१३
>
> One by one Krsna killed all the bulls and victoriously held the hand of Nila, taking an instant liking for her.

Then Krsna was duly married to Nila, and along with Balarama, Nanda, Sridama and others, returned to Vrindavana.

This differs from Srimati Satya's marriage in that Krsna killed the bulls in this, whereas Krsna tamed the bulls in Satya's marriage.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  The killed vs. tame point is a sufficiently minor point that it doesn't change my view that the Nappinnai story and the Satya story are somehow connected.  By the way, now I'm curious whether the Alwars' poems or any other works describe what happened to Nappinai/Nila after Krishna went to Mathura.  There are certainly plenty of stories of what happened to Radha, but I'm interested on stories that specifically say Nappinnai or Nila.

Comment: Actually, this is more like an Andal-type situation, where her bridegroom is forever the son of Nandagopa. It could also be possible that this story happens after kamsa is killed, because it is not stated after which chapter this story happens. Also, Krsna visited Vrindavana after delivering Shalva and demolishing the Saubha Vehicle, according to Padma Purana (?). So, this story could have happened even then.

Comment: Yeah, but the case of Andal is different, because Krishna wasn't present on Earth at the time.  In this case there's the possibility that Krishna and Nappinnai stayed together after they got married.  Perhaps some Alwar poem or something addresses what happened to her.  Also, I think it's more likely that this happened before Krishna killed Kamsa, both because it would better comport with the story of Radha and because Krishna traveling to Yashoda's brother's house and things like that sound more like the earlier part of Krishna's life.

Comment: Oops, I meant it **sounds** like an Andal type situation. I say it happened afterward because it conforms to the story narrated in the Bhagavatam. Because surely Krsna wouldn't have **left behind** his bride in Vrindavana and gone to Mathura, since that subject took up three or four chapters of his previous incarnation...

Comment: Well, what I'm thinking is maybe when Krishna went to Mathura, Napinnai also went (perhaps not in the same trip, but shortly after Krishna killed Kamsa).  And Napinnai may have been one of Krishna's main queens, but then later on there was some confusion and some people assumed that Krishna married all his queens post-Mathura, so the story of Nappinnai was transformed into the story of Satya.  But then people still had an awareness that Krishna loved a woman in Vrindavana, so that turned into a story of Krishna having an unmarried girlfriend.  That's just one possible scenario.

Comment: I just found an absolutely fascinating chapter of the Garuda Purana discussing Nappinnai: http://gdurl.com/0hAu It says that Nila was first born as the daughter of Agni, then she worshipped Vishnu in Tirupati, then she was reborn as the daughter of Yashoda's brother Kumbhaka, and then she was again reborn as the daughter of Nagnajit!  Perhaps what happened is that after Krishna married Nappinnai, Nappinnai died for some reason, and then she was reborn as Krishna's queen Satya.

Comment: @Keshav I'll tell you. Niladevi was first born as Nappinai.  And Nappinai's Amsa was born as Satya Devi. No one died. :)

Comment: Well, if she died it would explain how it's possible that Krishna married Nappinnai and yet he's not depicted as being with Nappinnai later in life.

Comment: @Keshav You know reading the Padma Purana chapter where Krsna returns to Vrindavana, I think it's likely that he married her then. Besides you do realise that by saying "there was some confusion", you are casting doubts on Vyasa and Shukadeva Gosvami. Or you are giving way to the thought that what they said was just hearsay.. Both of which are disastrous thoughts.

Comment: No, I don't even have the slightest doubt about Vyasa.  When I talk about confusion I'm talking about confusion on the part of interpolators, not confusion on the part of an incarnation of Vishnu. In any case, at least Madhvacharya says in his Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya that Krishna married Nappinnai before his Upanayana.

Comment: @Keshav Don't put everything you don't agree with in the hands of interpolators. If it was so then many scriptures would be interpolated. Try to analyse... you always like to dismiss whatever is different from the accepted version as interpolation...

Comment: I don't just dismiss everything I don't agree with as interpolations - I carefully apply principles of Mimamsa in making my determinations. It's a well-established principle of Mimamsa  that if you see two scriptural passages that appear to contradict one another, you should first assume that you're misinterpreting one or the other passage.  And then if you see no interpretation that would reconcile them, then you should investigate the possibility that one or the other passage is not authentic.

Comment: In any case, there is very strong evidence that, say, the descriptions of Radha in the Brahma Vaivarta Purana are interpolations.  So where I'm uncertain in this case is not whether there are interpolations, but why.  And I think a reasonable hypothesis is that interpolations about Radha arose because people developed the notion of Krishna having an unmarried girlfriend based on him having a wife before he went to Mathura.

Comment: @Keshav I wasn't talking about Radharani at all, because I know that you and I are not going to agree on that ;). I was actually talking about Srimati Satya, because you involved her in the interpolators list as the equivalent of Nappinnai (whom they didn't know about...)

Comment: Well, I wrote that comment back in October, before I came across that Garuda Purana chapter.  Now I think Nappinnai and Satya may both be real, and one died and was born as the other or one entered the body of the other or something.