# Which all early Hindu scriptures contain references about Shri Radha?

Tags: krishna, radha

I recently read an article on the internet claiming that Shri Radha might not be real but an imaginary character and the reason they gave was that although Shri Radha has been given much preference than Rukmini, Her reference is not found in any major Puranas of Lord Vishnu or Lord Krishna. Her reference is only found in Bramha Vaivarta Purana and texts written by Poet Jaidev. If She had been such an important part of Lord Krishna's life then She should have been mentioned in other major Vaishnav Puranas.

So, I wanted to check whether this is true and or not and if not, then which all Puranas or other important Hindu texts contains references about Her.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [References of Radha in the Itihasas?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9059/3500)

Comment: Also see this question [What scriptures describe Krishna's lover Nappinnai?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/3500)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Actually the Padma, Skanda, Narada, Brahmanda, Brahmavaivarta, Matsya (only one reference), Devi Bhagavata and Shiva Puranas talk about Radharani.

Comment: Yeah, as *Surya* mentioned above there are many Puranas that talk about Radha. And some Pancaratra and Tantra scriptures talk about Radha as well, to name a few: Brihad Brahma Samhita, Narada Pancaratra, Sanatkumara-samhita, Garga Samhita, Brihad-gautamiya-tantra, Urdhvamnaya-tantra. Purusa-bodhini Upanishad also known as Radhopanishad also tells about Radha.

Comment: Thanks everyone for mentioning the various sources of which I was unaware till now. However, I still can't understand why She had not been given any place in Vaishnava puranas like Shrimad Bhagawat, Vishnu Purana, Mahabharata, Harivamsa, etc. Please let me know if I am wrong. Also, can somebody please post the sources with some reference texts from these puranas so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Aby The Padma Purana and Narada Purana are both Vaishnava Puranas. I do not know about Vishnu Purana but in the Bhagavatam there are many indirect references to her. Harivamsa talks of Nila Devi who **may or may not be the same** as Radharani.

Comment: Aby and @Surya As far as I know there is no mention of Radha in the Vishnu Purana. And Nila Devi definitely in not Sri Radha, but is a different person. @ Aby: You can read some of indirect references to Radha in the Bhagavatam chapter 10.30 at http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/30 verses 24 and forward. I suggest you to read some of the purports to those verses where it is explained that those verses about unnamed gopi is referring to Radha, such as verse 10.30.28 http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/30/28 and 10.30.35-36 etc.

Comment: The Rig veda has mentioned the name of Radha and the synonyms at more than 24 locations. The Padma Purana also mentioned "Radha". The Radhopnishada has described the root definitions and also the synonyms of "Radha" as "Ramaa", "Shree", "Gopi", etc.

        The sages Sanak and Sanatan of the four Kumaras were considered to be among the pioneers who mentioned Radha, when they got higher God realisation.

Some Vedic excerpts/sources mentioning "Radha":

Text: “idaṁ hyanvojasāsutaṁ rādhānāṁ pate pivā tvasya girvaṇaḥ” (Ṛig Veda) Meaning: “O Shree Krishna, husband of Radha!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Srimati Radharani is mentioned in many Puranas like the Padma, Skanda, Narada, Brahmanda, Brahmavaivarta, Matsya, Shiva Puranas as well as the Devi Bhagavatam.

In the **Padma Purana**, her worship is mentioned in the 7th as well as 20th Chapters of the Bhumikanda (Volume 5 of Translation), in The Radhashtami and Radhadamodara Vrata.

Further, the Patalakhanda (Volume 6), Chapter 71 is about the greatness of Radhakrishna, and the subsequent few chapters describe the various Leelas of the divine couple, including one Leela where the Pandava **Arjuna** Is transported to Vrindavana, where he becomes a Gopika called Arjuni and is blessed with the darshan of Radhakrishna.

In the **Narada Purana**, (Volume 3), the 89th chapter describes the *Yugala Sahasranama* or 1000 names of both Radha and Krishna, where the first 500 names are Krishna's and the second 500 are Radharani’s names. It also includes, in its Uttarabhaga, a chapter about Vrindavana Mahatmya (Volume 5, Chapter 80), where Sage Narada becomes a gopi in Vrindavana to take part in Srimati Radharani’s Leelas.

In the **Skanda Purana**, Vaishnava Khanda, Bhagavata Mahatmya talks about Srimati Radharani. The 1st chapter (Volume 6) contains the famous statement, “Atma Tu Radhika Tasya” – Radharani is Krishna's soul. The Vasudeva Mahatmya (Volume 7), Chapters 16 and 17 describe Goloka and the manifestation of Radhakrishna for Narada.

In the **Brahmanda Purana**, Upodghata Parva, the last few chapters tell the story of Parashurama. In these chapters, Parashurama receives the hymn called Krishna Prema-Amrta from Rishi Agastya. He goes to Kailasa to meet Lord Shiva, where he chops off Lord Ganesha’s tusk. When Parvati Devi is furious with Parashurama, Lord Krishna and Radharani arrive from Goloka to appease Parvati. Their arrival and subsequent stotra is described in the 42nd and 43rd chapters of the Upodghata Parva (Volume 2 of Brahmanda Purana). The Stotra ‘Grhe Radha Vane Radha’ is also said to be from this Purana.

The **Matsya Purana**, when listing the goddesses of various cities, says, “Rukmini Dvaravatyam Tu **Radha Vrindavane Vane**.”

In the **Shiva Purana**, the Yuddhakanda of Rudrasamhita contains the story of Shankhachuda, who is actually Sridama, the Sakha of Lord Krishna in Goloka, who incarnates as a demon due to the curse of Radharani. In this, the 30th and 31st Chapter narrate how Lord Krishna and Radha (owing to this being a Shiva-centric Purana), plead forgiveness from Lord Shiva.

The **Brahmavaivarta Purana** is completely about Radhakrishna, though owing to a considerable number of interpolations in this Purana, and it's being well known, I leave it unquoted.

The **Devi Bhagavata Purana** dedicates its entire Navama Skandha (Ninth Canto) to the glories of Radhakrishna and their Leelas in Goloka and the rest of the universe.

Coming to **Srimad Bhagavatam**, there are many who say that Shukabrahma, who recited the Bhagavatam, was a pure devotee of Radhakrishna, and so uttering their pastimes would cause him to lose his consciousness and therefore leave the Purana incomplete. Hence he refers to her using common nouns such as ‘Kaachit’ (One Girl), ‘Saa Vadhuh’ (That Bride (of Krishna)), and ‘Priya’, (Beloved).

Apart from these references, the sloka [*Anayaradhito Nunam*](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/30/28) gives her name in the phrase *Aa**radhi**to* - as purported by Sri Vishvanatha Chakravarti.

It is Radharani who delivers the famous ['Bhramara Gita'](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/47) where she talks to a bee thinking it to be Krishna's messenger when Uddhava visits Vrindavana.

Also, the Second Canto, Fourth Chapter, when Shukabrahma Rishi says the Dhyana Slokas, he [meditates upon Lord Hari in his Eternal Abode](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/4/14) with all his Shaktis and Opulences. The name he gives to Vishnu’s Energy is ‘Raadhas’.

Apart from that, as user @brahmajijnasa said, the Brihad Brahma Samhita, Narada Pancaratra, Sanatkumara-samhita, Garga Samhita, Brihad-gautamiya-tantra, Urdhvamnaya-tantra and the Purusa-bodhini Upanishad give references to Srimati Radharani.

The **Narada Pancharatra** gives the Radha Kavacha and the Radha Sahasranama Stotra as told by Lord Shiva to Devi Parvati.

The **Garga Samhita** is also devoted to the story of Radhakrishna, and how the divine couple performed their Leelas in Vrindavana, and also describes their separation and eventual reunion in Siddhashrama, after the elapse of the hundred-year curse of separation.

EDIT: In the **Vishnu Purana**, during the description of Rasa Leela in [Chapter 13](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/visnu-purana/chapter-93/topic-1) of Book 5, there are seven slokas (slokas 32-38) describing Krishna leaving the Rasa Mandala and going off with a special Gopi into the forest. The other Gopis also describe their footprints, and Krishna's adorning her with flowers and leaving her some distance away. This is almost the same as in the Bhagavatam. The word used here (where there it is Anayaradhito) is *Vishnur **Abhyarchito** Yaya* - Vishnu was worshipped extensively by her. Therefore we can infer that this Gopika is Srimati Radharani.

Comment: @Surya Is Narada Pancharatra avaliable online...? I'm interested in reading Narada Pancharatra...

Comment: @Tezz A quick Google Search tells me there is only the original Sanskrit text for the **full** Pancharatra, individual stotras like Radhasahasranama, Sri Radhakavacha, Krsna's glories have English translations.

Comment: @Surya and all others, thanks a lot for citing all the sources. Its good to find all such information and also an eye opener for all the misleading sites that claim that Shri Radha is an imaginary character. I'll link this question and answer on the original site (speakingtree.com) also from where i read the misleading information so that other people also do not get misguided.

Comment: @Surya Haha, the Vishnu Purana reference would only be remotely convincing to someone who already believed that Radha was the Gopi mentioned in the Srimad Bhagavatam.

Comment: @Surya By the way, you can read the Narada Pancharatra in English here: http://vishnudut1926.blogspot.com/2015/11/shree-narada-pancaratram-english.html

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Which is why I added "it is almost similar to Bhagavatam". Why do you think both Vyasa's father and son would specifically mention Krsna's girlfriend? (I am not going to start this debate again, so let's leave it at that point.)

Comment: @Surya Well, I certainly think that the Vishnu Purana and the Srimad Bhagavatam are describing the same story, I just don't see any reason to believe that that favorite Gopi is Radha.  I certainly don't believe that whoever that favorite Gopi was dwells in Goloka.  But I think it's possible that that favorite Gopi is Nappinnai (whose existence I'm also undecided on).

Comment: @Keshav Thanks for the link, but the print is not very good.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes I know your views on Krsna's girlfriend, hence I said let us not continue, since I doubt either will come to a consensus.

Comment: Yeah, good to know that the Vishnu Purana tells the same thing as Bhagavatam. So you are still not convinced that the Brahma-vaivarta Purana is not full of interpolations? Btw, it would be a good thing to add some verses in your answer that explain for what reason we should believe that Radha is that special gopi the Vishnu Purana and Bhagavatam are referring to.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa if you are convinced that Brahma Vaivarta telling about Radha is interpolation. Then let me tell that the Very Khanda (Prakriti khanda) that glorifies Radha is one of the only sources which contain story of Vishnu becoming Shaligrama. And by curse of Radha only, Sudama became ShakhaChooda and Tulasi cursed Vishnu to become Shaligrama for killing ShankhaChuuda. So if Radha is interpolation, then Shaligrama is also interpolation.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa also, if we consider that it might be interpolation, then the same story "verse to verse" is in Shiva Purana, how Radha cursed Sudama to become ShankhaChuuda, how he was killed and how Vishnu was cursed to become Stone for killing him. First of all a Shiva Puraana will never let a Vishnu centred part to be copied in it, and that too adding an interpolation is even hard as Shaiva will refute. So if story of Radha is really interpolation, than Shiva Purana would have never added it that too verse by verse. If Radha is interpolation, then Shaligrama is also.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Who says that I think Brahma-vaivarta Purana (BVP) is interpolated? I was referring to our member *Surya* who said in his post, see above, that he thinks BVP has "a considerable number of interpolations". Personally I think there is not a single verse interpolated in the BVP! There is no proof that anything is interpolated there. Thanks for your remark on Shiva Purana, though. Yeah, it's quite unlikely that Shiva Purana might be interpolated in Vaishnava matters if such content is to be found in Vaishnava centered texts.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa "*.....you are still not convinced that the Brahma-vaivarta Purana is **not** full of interpolations?*" Oh God! I did not see that "**not**". Actually I had been explaining to KeshavSrinivasan why BVP is not interpolated, so I thought you are also saying it **is** interpolated. I swear I read your comment "**two**" times, but still did not see a **"not"** ,   ;P . BTW, Devi Puraana also has the Prakriti Khand exact verse by verse, again a Shaakta puraan will never let a Vaishnava centered part, or at least remove Vaishnava glories from it, but it did not do anything such.

Comment: @AnuragSingh haha, you are not the only one who does not see what I have to say, when I chatting with Keshav Srinivasan on this website's chat he also sometimes doesn't see or simply doesn't understand what I told him. I don't understand why is that thing happening, It's a mystery to me. Perhaps I was cursed in one of my past lives that people will not understand what I want to tell them, haha. Keshav believes that many things are interpolated in the Puranas, but I don't. When you said Devi Purana are you referring to the Devi Bhagavata Purana?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa yes, Devi Bhagawata Puraana. I call it shortly as Devi Puraana (and this name is not incorrect also). And Haha, no curse is there. It's just that we readers want to read 2 Puraanas in one third of a minute. Haha. Also it's true that seeing everything as interpolation just because it does not match your view points is baseless. Radha is true, whether or not KS or anyone else believes. Interpolations are there, when something is not agreeing with the whole rest of other Puraanas, and Radha story is in 3 Puraanas as far as I have read.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes, Sri Radha is definitely a true goddess. Our mod Keshav has repeatedly said he is not sure is she true or not, perhaps he was cursed. ;)

Comment: @brahmajijnasa haha, yes. Maybe. Actually, saying "***Radha is not real***" is like saying "***Shaligrama worship is not real***" because only and only because of Raadhaa's curse Sudaamaa became ShankhaChuuda,married Tulasi and Tulasi(not Vrinda of Jalandhara) cursed Vishnu to become Shaligrama. Vrinda had cursed Vishnu to get separated from wife, and forget about his powers in one of his life's (in Raama avatar) . So if Radha is "*false*" , then ShankhaChuuda is also false, then Tulasi is false, then Shaligrama is also false. It is absurd to say Radha is just an imagnry charcter and intrpoltn

Comment: Where did you get about the word Raadhas in SB 2.4.14.. did anyone interpret it as Radha?

Comment: Didn’t know you had this answer. Very nice. I’m waiting for one reference to show Radha = Nila and hence one of the Ashtabharya of Bhagwan. It’ll be one very satisfying thing. Does Narada Purana mention Nila or any other name in the sahasranama?

Comment: @Archit I haven't read the Sahasranama fully, maybe I will go through and see if Neela is mentioned

Comment: @KrishnaVarna I interpreted it myself as a possible meaning for the potency of Radharani, as being the spiritual energy of the Lord.

Comment: @Surya I have seen that interpretation of SB 2.4.14 as Radha in Vedanta Syamantaka [here](https://archive.org/details/Vedanta-syamantaka.balaKrishnaGoswamiEdition/page/n24/mode/1up) / [here](https://archive.org/details/srivedantasyamantakabaladevavidhyabhusan/page/n16/mode/1up)

Answer (score 7):

Most of the people here have given references from smritis and Tantras. But radha is mentioned in one of the 108 muktika canon upanishads. Namely [Gopala tapani upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopala_Tapani_Upanishad) -

> "The central character of the text is Radha who is described as the Shakti of Krishna, her devotion and discussion of Gopala Krishna. Gopala Krishna is presented as identical to the nondual Absolute Reality (Atman-Brahman), the sat-cit-ananda, the Guru, the Om and the object of Vedanta, who can be reached by devotion to love. It is an important text to the Vaiṣṇava schools of Hinduism, particularly the Gaudiya Vaishnavas of Bengal region of South Asia.
>
> The text is listed as 95th in the Telugu language Muktika anthology of 108 Upanishads."

[English translation](http://www.vrindavana.net/academy/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Gopala-Tapani_Upanishad.pdf) of Gopala Tarani Upanishad.

People should stop believing in these modern day "mythologists" and "folklorists" who use Hindu holy books for entertainment. Specially this devdutt pattnaik guy.

Also this upanishad talks about Krishna and radha from an advaita and vedanta point of view, the dualistic schools of madhvacharya and chaitanya really didn't care much about philosophy or atma etc, their movement was purely of bhakti so i don't think any vaishnavas will make up and add this upanishad into Vedas.

Furthermore all the claims of westerners have been wrong- ganesha being interpolation wrong, Krishna being 2 wrong, purusha sukta- yajnopaveeta interpolation wrong there is 90 percent chance that this claim is wrong too.

Comment: You may also add relevant verses from that Upanishad. You can get English translation of Gopala Tapini Upanishad from [here](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-atharva-veda/gopala-tapaniya-upanishad/).

Comment: @Pandya the link you provided is no more valid.

Comment: @RaRa Thanks for pointing out, updated the link.