# Why Radha plays such an important role in Gaudiya Vaishnavism despite her name is not mentioned anywhere in Mahabharata?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, radha

The name of Radha is not found in the Mahabharata and Harivamsha. Even Bhagavad Purana, the most sacred scripture for Gaudiya Vaishnavas, did not mention Radha. However, Radha has supreme importance in Gaudiya Vaishnavism. How come Radha promoted to such an elevated position from nowhere?

Comment: You might want to read [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14059/3662) to know about the scriptures that mention Radharani. Your question is still very valid though, about her importance in Gaudiya Tradition.

Comment: As far as I know, Radha is mentioned in Bhagavatam as Aradhika(devotee/one who does Aradhna/worship) during Rasa Lila of Sri Krishna. There is only one mention of Aradhika.