# Question regarding RadheKrishna

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, radha

Why is there no mention of Radha in Srimad Bhagavatham. Srimad Bhagavatham doesn't seem to mention anything about Radha, What puranas mention about Radha?

Comment: Devibhagavata purana, Shiva Purana, Brahmavaivarta Purana, Skanda Purana, Padma Purana, Naradiya Purana. Gaudiyas argue that the oblique reference in the Bhagavatam to a 'most beloved gopi' with whom Krishna suddenly exited from the Rasamandala indicates only Srimati Radha. They interpret the word अनयाराधितो in BG:10:30:28 as 'with this Radha', instead of the standard 'with her by whom he was worshipped'.

Comment: Ohh I would be glad if this was posted as an answer with suitable references

Comment: [This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/which-all-early-hindu-scriptures-contain-references-about-shri-radha) has answers to your question on which scriptures describe Radharani.

Comment: Thank you soo much