# Who is Vishnu's wife Nila?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi

Can somebody give me some information on the Goddess Nila?

I read about Her in this question: [What scriptures describe Krishna's lover Nappinnai?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/36])

Vishnu's other wives, Lakshmi and BhumiDevi are goddesses of Wealth and Earth respectively.

What is Goddess Nila the Goddess of?

Comment: Para is the highest form of Vishnu found only in Sri Vaikuntha also called Nityavibhuti or Moksha, along with his consorts Sri, Bhumi and Nila and surrounded by Nityasuries, like Ananta, Garuda, Visvaksena and a host of Muktas(liberated souls). The Alvars have sung in great ecstasy about this beatific form of the Lord. The Para form is called Para Vasudeva or Sthula(gross)-Vasudeva with four arms, holding conch, disc, mace and lotus.From this link :http://www.srivaishnavan.com/upload1/srivaish3.html.

Comment: *And that is why in Mahavishnu puja or in panchayatana puja  we say like this-Sri Bhumi Nila Sameta sri Mahavishnum dhyami avahayami

Comment: @Rickross What is Nila Devi the goddess of?

Comment: I'm not sure.Need to search .

Comment: You may be interested in this question I just posted about the Nila Sukta of the Yajur Veda, which is addressed to Nila Devi: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10773/36

Comment: Does anybody know what Nila devi is goddess of?

Comment: I just posted another question about Nappinnai: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10901/36

Comment: The marriage story is already mentioned in the linked post. Read the answer.

Comment: This question has it - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/what-scriptures-describe-krishnas-lover-nappinnai

Comment: Nila Devi is one of the shanmahisi of Krishna, Kalamdhi, lakshna, badhra, janbavathi, Mitravinda

Answer (score 1):

neelA of KrushNa avtaar is different from neelA of vishNu-vaikuNTa

neelA of vishNu-vaikuNTa is connected to three steps of vishNu as described in **chapter 227 of padma puraaN** :

> " The pervading with his third step is done in the highest abode. One step of him was here also. His vibhUti with the third step is perpetual, (while) the step (on the earth) is non-perpetual. "

> " This nArAyaṇI, the mother of the world, is the resort of the entire world. The entire immobile and mobile world has resorted to (i.e. depends upon) her glance. The existence and the dissolution of the world is due to her opening and closing (her) eyes. This great lakshmI is the first of all. She has three constituents (viz. sattva, rajas and tamas). She is the greatest goddess. She of a visible and invisible form, remains after having pervaded everything. The great goddess having seen the entire universe void, filled that entire (universe) with her own lustre. That lakshmI is the Earth only, well-known as **goddess neelA**. Being the support of the world, she has resorted to the form of the earth. She herself would be of the form of **neelA due to her liquid form of the nature of water etc.** She has obtained the form of lakshmI. She is of the nature of wealth and speech. Thus, she, the goddess of the world, has resorted to vishNu. O you of an auspicious face, all the varieties of knowledge would be (i.e. are) her forms. "