# What is the procedure for performing Vishnu panchayatanam?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, rituals, mantras, puja

For shiva panchayatanam, usually Rudra namaka Chamaka and purushasukta will be recited and abhishekam is performed during shiva panchayatana puja.

Similarly for Vishnu panchayatana puja, what is the process? Which veda mantras will be recited Apart from Purushasuktham?

Basically I would like to know the veda mantras which will be recited for the respective panchayatana puja. I want to know more especially for Vishnu panchayatana puja and veda mantras which are part of in this scope.

Comment: Panchayatana worship is a practice done by Smarthas, so I'm not that familiar with it, but at least the five Vedic hymns used by Sri Vaishnavas when worshiping Vishnu are the Purusha Sukta, the Narayana Sukta, the Sri Sukta, the Bhu Sukta, and Nila Sukta (which I discuss in my question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10773/36)).

Comment: Puja Vidhnams(like Sri Sukta Vidhana OR Purusha Sukta Vidhna) are the same for all Puja, so the basic mantras are the same that are used and does not change with whose Panchayatana it is, like Shiva Panchayatana or Vishnu Panchayatana.Only change is with respect to where the Deities should be placed and who should be be invoked first in the Puja .For eg,in your case the Saligrama is to be placed in the middle as opposed to the Banalinga which is what is done in a Shiva Panchaytana.Also MahaVishnu is to be invoked first.

Comment: *During Avisekams ,afaik ,Rudram(Namakam,Chamakam),Sri Suktam & Purusha Suktam are to be recited at the barest minimum.

Comment: BTW let me also add a word caution-You should not learn a Panchayatana Puja on your own from the web.Its better to learn it  orally(along with mantras with the swaras) from a Pundit.