# Why did Goddess Lakshmi choose Lord Vishnu as her consort?

Tags: vishnu, puranas, lakshmi

Lakshmi is also called **Sri**. Lakshmi personifies wealth, riches, beauty, happiness,
grace, charm and splendour. She was born from the churning of the primordial ocean 
(Samudra manthan) and she chose Vishnu as her eternal consort and is the divine strength of Lord Vishnu.

My question is - **Why did Goddess Lakshmi choose Lord Vishnu as her consort ? Is there any specific reason for that & What was her criteria for the same?**

Comment: They are consorts from time immemorial. Durvasa curses Indra that they would loose all "Sri" or glory or wealth and thus she disappears. After churning She comes back and chooses Her eternal consort Sri Hari.

Comment: @TheDestroyer - yes agree on this point. But the point of my question is little different , it's more related to qualities of husband. And abt. what were the specific reasons of choosing vishnu before and after  the churning of ocean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After she emerges from the Churning of the Ocean, Lakshmi examines the Devas, Gandharvas, Asuras, etc., to find a suitable husband.  But she finds that they're all lacking in one or more good qualities, as described in [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> Someone who has undergone **great austerity** has not yet **conquered anger**. Someone possesses **knowledge**, but he has not **conquered material desires**. Someone is a **very great personality**, but he cannot **conquer lusty desires**. Even a great personality depends on something else. How, then, can he be the **supreme controller**?  Someone may possess **full knowledge of religion** but still not be **kind to all living entities**. In someone, whether human or demigod, there may be **renunciation**, but that is not the cause of liberation. Someone may possess **great power** and yet be unable to **check the power of eternal time**. Someone else may have **renounced attachment to the material world**, yet he cannot compare to the **Supreme Personality of Godhead**. Therefore, no one is **completely freed from the influence of the material modes of nature**.  Someone may have **longevity** but not have **auspiciousness** or **good behavior**. Someone may have both auspiciousness and good behavior, but the duration of his life is not fixed. Although such demigods as Lord Śiva have **eternal life**, they have inauspicious habits like living in crematoriums. And even if others are well qualified in all respects, they are not devotees of the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

So rejecting everyone else, she chooses Vishnu, since he's the only one in possession of all auspicious qualities:

> In this way, after full deliberation, the goddess of fortune accepted Mukunda as her husband because although He is independent and not in want of her, He possesses **all transcendental qualities and mystic powers and is therefore the most desirable**.Approaching the Supreme Personality of Godhead, the goddess of fortune placed upon His shoulders the garland of newly grown lotus flowers, which was surrounded by humming bumblebees searching for honey. Then, expecting to get a place on the bosom of the Lord, she remained standing by His side, her face smiling in shyness.

By the way, note that this is only the story of how Vyuha Vasudeva, the form of Vishnu who lies down in the ocean of milk, married the goddess Lakshmi who was born from the Churning of Vishnu.  But Para Vasudeva, the eternal Vishnu who dwells in Paramapadam, is married to an eternal Lakshmi.  (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36) for more information on these forms of Vishnu.  Para Vasudeva has two other wives, Bhu Devi and Nila Devi whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10773/36).)

Comment: @keshavShrinivasan - Yes , the Para Vasudeva concept is new to me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: "Shiva ... they have inauspicious habits like living in crematoriums." - ha ha :) I can't believe SB actually says that!

Comment: @sv. I think It's ISKCON translation. First Shiva is not Demi God and living in Cremation grounds is not inauspicious at all. Whoever dies goes there. We need to see Sanskrit verses and preferably we must be see other version of Bhagavatam such as Gita press Edition. Anyways, Puranas are like that. It could have said Shiva is Lakshmi's brother without dragging Him into it. .

Comment: @SV. In Gita press version there is no mentioning of name shiva. I don't know abt the other versions though.

Comment: @TheDestroyer You're right! The Sanskrit verse at https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/22 is talking in general about other gods. No mention of Shiva in the verse. Yet the tr. magically adds all sorts of things :P

Comment: @TheDestroyer **We need to see Sanskrit verses** What about the verses themselves?Aren't they hugely interpolated?I think this Purana is easily the most interpolated one..

Comment: @Rickross No, the Srimad Bhagavatam is very well-preserved.  By far the most interpolated Purana is the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50081/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-why-did-goddess-lakshmi-choose-lord-vi).

Comment: "Although such demigods as Lord Śiva have eternal life, they have inauspicious habits like living in crematoriums." - Pls use better translations. Thank you.

Comment: I have read a different version where Mother Lakshmi says she chose Mahavishnu because She saw Him the best,then Lord Vishnu says that Lord Shiva is the best(guess this is in the Shiva Puran or such scripture)