# Why Lord Vishnu made Devi Lakshmi his consort?

Tags: vishnu, marriage, lakshmi

Devi Sati is reborn as Devi Parvati, the daughter of Himavat and Mainavati, and is named Parvati. To marry to Lord Shiva she did tapasya. Due to Which Lord Shiva accepted her as wife.

Has Devi Lakshmi done any tapsya of Lord Vishnu to be his consort. Or is it she springs with other precious things from the foam of the ocean of milk when it is churned by the gods and demons for the recovery of Amṛta. She appeared while churning ocean and she choose to be wife of Lord Vishnu.

Why Lord Vishnu made Devi Lakshmi as his consort? As we know Devi Parvati did tapasya to be consort of Lord Shiva.

Comment: Possible partial Duplicate of - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/why-did-goddess-lakshmi-choose-lord-vishnu-as-her-consort

Comment: @SwiftPushkar It is explanation abt y Devi Lakshmi chose Lord Vishnu as consort. I'm asking Y Lord Vishnu chose Devi Lakshmi as consort. As Devi Parvati did Tapsaya to be consort of Lord Shiva. There is no ref about Devi Lakshmi doing any thing for Lord Vishnu. I don't think it is duplicate.

Comment: Yes , I understood that your question is different that's why not voted to close.  But in the second paragraph you are asking "Or is it she choose to be wife of Lord Vishnu.?" So i think both of these are your question. :)

Comment: Goddess Lakshmi is said to be eternal consort of Lord Vishnu. And "eternal" literally means eternal, ie since no beginning in the past, and no end in the future. She was consort of Lord Vishnu even before this universe was created. She is the wife of Lord Vishnu throughout all eternity. That is possibly the reason of why Lord Vishnu chose Goddess Lakshmi to be his consort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Goddess Lakshmi choose Lord Vishnu as her consort?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/why-did-goddess-lakshmi-choose-lord-vishnu-as-her-consort)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the biggest confusions that there was no Goddess Lakshmi before Samudra Manthana.

Goddess Lakshmi was actually daughter of Bhrigu & Khyati earlier and got married to Lord Vishnu. Indra showed disrespect to her (or sage Durvasa in some stories) and she made her abode in the abysmal depth of the sea and later emerged during Samudra Manthan. Read in more detail about other incarnations of Goddess Lakshmi from [Vishnu Purana](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp042.htm).

**As per SATI KHAND and PARVAT KHAND of Shiva Purana**:

Goddess Sati gave up her body in Daksha Yajna and born to other parents (Himalaya and Maina.) as Parvati. It was the grief of Sati's death that led Shiva to exact vengeance. **Later, Shiva had no interest in worldly life**.

But Tarakasur got a boon from Lord Bhrahma that

> except Shiva's son nobody should be able to kill him.

When Tarakasur became biggest threat to Indra, Indra called Kamadeva and told him that

> The demon king Tarakasur could be killed only by such a person who was the son of Shiva. Indra instructed Kamadeva to arouse passion in lord Shiva, so that he agrees to marry Parvati.

But when Kamdeva was trying his best, the third eye of lord Shiva got opened and Kamadeva was reduced to ashes. After that Narada preaches and Parvati does penance.

So it was different story altogether for Goddess Parvati.

But Goddess Lakshmi didn't give up her body, she just changed her abode. So, she was already married to Lord Vishnu. But in Samudra Manthana, not only Vishnu (in his Kurma form) but also Devas and Asuras were engaged and all had equal right on whatever emerged from that exercise. So in my opinion, Goddess Lakshmi had to do that Lila (of choosing a husband) but after this point this question is exactly duplicate of [Why did Goddess Lakshmi choose Lord Vishnu as her consort?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/why-did-goddess-lakshmi-choose-lord-vishnu-as-her-consort) so you may find better answers there. And one more point, during Samudra Manthana no body denied if something was given after mutual consent, even Lord Shiva accepted Halahala.

Comment: "his question is exactly duplicate of Why did Goddess Lakshmi choose Lord Vishnu as her consort?" If a question is exact duplicate, vote to close. Answering is not the way to say it is a duplicate.

Comment: @NogShine I said after this point...till that point I think answer is needed...