# Is Radha mentioned in Garuda Purana?

Tags: radha, garuda-purana

Is Radha, the consort of Sri Krishna mentioned in Garuda Purana? If yes, which chapter of which Samhita is she mentioned?

Comment: Hello! Pls. see  this answer , there is list  of puranas where Radha is mentioned in that.- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14191/5620

Comment: So for time being I am closing this question as duplicate as there is no need of a separate post inquiring whether the ref. are found in other puranas or not. The existing answer can be edited to answer your query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which all early Hindu scriptures contain references about Shri Radha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/which-all-early-hindu-scriptures-contain-references-about-shri-radha)

Comment: There’s a brief mention of her in the Garuda Purāṇa : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10901/what-is-the-relation-between-krishnas-cowherd-wife-nappinnai-and-his-queen-saty

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes I have read that answer but there is no reference from Garuda Purana. I am asking if she is mentioned in Garuda Purana.