# Where does the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ghatikasatham Ammal discuss Radha?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, radha

Unlike the Gaudiya Vaishnava and Pushtimarga sects, the Sri Vaishnava does not place much emphasis on Krishna’s lover Radha.  This is for multiple reasons.  First of all, Sri Vaishnavas emphasize the Vishnu Purana and the Srimad Bhagavatam, neither of which mention Radha.  So the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Chinna Jeeyar Swami and the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Velukkudi Krishnan Swami say that Radha did not actually exist as a Gopi during the time of Krishna, but instead is a personification of the Gopis’ Bhakti towards Krishna.  Second of all, Sri Vaishnavas believe in a similar figure to Radha, Krishna’s cowherd wife Nappinnai, whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/36) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchhttps://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=nr-trlc4yMgange.com/q/10901/36).

But I just found out that one Sri Vaishnava Acharya has sung about Radha.  [Here](https://youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=nr-trlc4yMg) is what the Sri Vaishnava lecturer U. Ve. Ananthapadmanabhachariar Swami says in the 3 minute mark of this lecture:

> Jayadeva, Lilasukha, and **Ghatikasatham Ammal** have all sung beautifully about Radha, the personification of Krishna's mercy.

Now Jayadeva was the author of the Gita Govinda, a 12th century poem epic poem about Radha and Krishna.  And Lilasukha was the author of the Krishna Karnamrita, a 13th century collection of poems in praise of Krishna.  These works are venerated by Gaudiya Vaishnavas, though the predate the founding of the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect.

But Ghatikasatham was a Sri Vaishnava Acharya.  He was a shishya of Brahmatantra Svatantra Jeeyar, founder of Parakala Matham, and guru of Adivan Sadagopan, founder of Ahobilam Matham.  (Parakala Matham and Ahobilam Matham are major Vadakalai Sri Vaishnava Mathams.)  My question is, in what work does Ghatikasatham Ammal discuss Radha?

Comment: Recently I learnt that in his Gopala Vimshati, Sri Manavala Mamunigal also has sung about Srimati Radha as the companion of Lord Rajagopala.

Comment: @Surya First of all the Gopala Vimshati was composed by Vedanta Desikan, not Manavala Mamunigal.  Second of all, it has no mention of Radha.  Verse 18 mentions Nappinnai though: https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Gopala%20Vimsati.pdf

Comment: Actually there are two Gopala Vimshatis, one by Swami Desikan and another by Swami Manavala Mamunigal. You can listen to the explanations of all 20 of the latter here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4yl6n2vr3oeh0Grt9zj9wzH6pzYudVTg.

Comment: And the 8th verse of this Gopala Vimshati says "Radha Sange Virachita Rutukam Rajagopalam Eede".