# When did Narakasura perform his atrocities on Svarga?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, krishna, bhagavata-purana

Narakasura, the son of Lord Varaha and Bhudevi, is quite famous. It is because of him that Lord Krsna was able to get the name Murari, Narakari, as well as whole festival dedicated to him (Deepavali). Oh, also Krsna was able to marry 16100 princesses.

Narakasura's story is described in the [59th Chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/59) of the Dasama Skandha of Srimad Bhagavatam (as well as many other scriptures, but we will restrict ourselves to Bhagavatam in this question). Since he is the son of Bhudevi and Varaha, it can be logical to assume that he could have been born anytime from the beginning of our Kalpa to the beginning of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.

That he is very old is vouched for by Sugriva in the Ramayana, where in the Kishkindha Kanda, Sarga 42 he directs the monkeys to search for Sitadevi, but cautions them against going to [Narakasura's kingdom](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga42/kishkindha_42_frame.htm) (Sloka 31).

Also in the Mahabharata, Udyoga Parva, Chapter 130, Vidura tells everyone how Krsna slew Narakasura, who was **Aneka Yuga Varshayuh**, ['Of Many Yugas in Age'](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/itihaas/mahabharat/text-with-translation/vol-iii/chapter-201/topic-1) (Verse 44).

But taking all this into consideration, it is surprising that Narakasura would remain dormant for so long and attack Svargaloka only when **Krsnavatara** happens. At least, that is what is presumed from the 59th Chapter of Dasama Skandha, where it is said that having lost all his riches, as well as Varuna's umbrella and Mother Aditi's earrings to Narakasura, indra rushed to Krsna for help.

So, did Narakasura really wait that long to attack Svarga? Or did Indra just wait for the right time and right person to lodge his complaint? If the latter is the case, when exactly did Narakasura conquer Svarga?

Comment: http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/itihaas/mahabharat/text-with-translation/vol-iii/chapter-201/topic-1 In this link verse 48 or page 4. When vidura describes Krishna's might He says that Krishna killed Jarasandha but I've heard that Slayer of jarasandha was Bhima, he was assisted by Keshava.

Comment: @Yogi Vidura might just be listing the Kings who were killed through Krsna's intelligence. Even so there is a [beautiful verse in Srimad Bhagavatam](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/7/34-35) which says that all the demons listed were either killed by krsna himself or Krsna **in the form of Balarama, Arjuna or Bhima**. So we can conclude that it is Krsna who under the name "Bhima" killed Jarasandha.

Comment: I agree with you but there are more people with different philosophical or personal views how is it justified for them. We are okay with this because we believe that Krishna or Shri Hari Vishnu is antaryami for everybody.

Comment: [Related not duplicate] [How did Varaha's son Narakasura become evil?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8123/3500)

Comment: @Yogi The first sentence of my comment is for those people. Jarasandha was killed through Krsna's **intelligence**.

Comment: @Surya Narakasura was born after the episode of Varaha in Kokamukha, where he instituted the current Shraddha practices; see this excerpt from Brahma Purana: http://gdurl.com/WYWt I'm not sure when that was.  In any case, Narakasura may been troubling the gods for a while, but his trouble reached its peak in the time of Krishna, and it was divinely ordained that Krishna would be born at that time to defeat him.  It's just like it was divinely ordained that Ayyappa would be born when Mahishi's trouble reached its peak, so he could defeat her.

Answer (score 1):

Towards the close of the Dwapara and beginning of the Kali ages.

Lord Vishnu listed what his incarnations in the present kalpa will be to Narada in the beginning of the kalpa and Bhishma recevied the boon of the past, present, and the futire by Krishna after war and from the boon he recevied, Bhishma told Yudhisthira what Lord Vishnu told Narada about his incarnation as Krishna.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c039.htm

> **Towards the close of the Dwapara and beginning of the Kali ages**, I shall again appear in the world taking birth in the city of Mathura for the purpose of slaying Kansa. There, after slaying innumerable Danavas that will be thorns in the side of the deities, I shall take up my residence in Kusasthali at the city of Dwaraka. While residing in that city **I shall slay the Asura Naraka, the son of 'the Earth,--him, that is, who will do an injury to Aditi**, as also some 'other Danavas of the names of Muru and Pitha. **Slaying also another foremost of Danavas, viz., the lord of Pragjyotisha**, I shall transplant his delightful city furnished with diverse kinds of wealth into Dwaraka.

---

Arjuna later listed the feats of Krishna in Udyoga Parva and told Sanjaya to send the messaeg to Duryodhana and Sanjaya told Duryodhana the message of Krishna's feats and if Duryodhana desires war, how he will lose and listed the feats of Krishna and one of them is the slaying of Narakasura.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05048.htm

> The Asuras had a city named Pragjyotisha, which was formidable, inaccessible and unbearable. **It was there that the mighty Naraka, the son of the Earth, kept the jewelled ear-rings of Aditi, having brought them by force.** **The very gods, who, fearless of death, assembled together with Sakra at their head were incapable of conquering him.** Beholding Kesava's prowess and might, and weapon that is irresistible, and knowing also the object of his birth, the gods employed him for the destruction of those Asuras. **Vasudeva, too, endued with all the divine attributes that ensure success, agreed to undertake that exceedingly difficult task.** In the city of Nirmochana **that hero slew six thousand Asuras, and cutting into pieces innumerable keen-edged shafts, he slew Mura and hosts of Rakshasas**, and then entered that city. It was there, that **an encounter took place between the mighty' Naraka and Vishnu of immeasurable strength. Slain by Krishna, Naraka lay lifeless there**, like a Karnikara tree uprooted by the wind. **Having slain the Earth's son, Naraka, and also Mura, and having recovered those jewelled ear-rings, the learned Krishna of unparalleled prowess came back, adorned with beauty and undying fame.**