# Which scripture says that Varaha was father of Narakasura?

Tags: krishna, earth, varaha

The [following](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07027.htm) excerpt from the Mahabaratha clarifies that **Narakasura was the son of Earth** and Krishna (in another form) gave him a boon on Earth's request:

> Vasudeva replied unto him, saying, 'Listen, O Partha, to this secret and ancient history as it is, O sinless one! I have four forms, eternally engaged as I am in protecting the worlds. Dividing my own Self, I ordain the good of the worlds. One form of mine, staying on the earth, is engaged in the practice of ascetic austerities. Another beholdeth the good and the evil deeds in the world. My third form, coming into the world of men, is engaged in action. My fourth form lieth down in sleep for a thousand years. **The form of mine which awaketh from sleep at the end of a thousand years, granteth, upon awakening, excellent boons to persons deserving of them. The earth, knowing (on one occasion) that that time had come, asked of me a boon for (her son) Naraka. Hear, O Partha, what that boon was. Possessed of the Vaishnava weapon, let my son become incapable of being slain by the gods and the Asuras. It behoveth thee to grant me that weapon. Hearing this prayer, I then gave, in days of old, the supreme and infallible Vaishnava weapon to the Earth's son.** I said also at that time these words, 'O Earth, let this weapon be infallible for the protection of Naraka. None will be able to slay him. Protected by this weapon, thy son will always, in all the worlds, be invincible and crush all hostile hosts.' Saying, So be it! the intelligent goddess went away, her wishes fulfilled.

In Baghavatham, there are many slokhas stating that Naraka was the son of Earth, but in which slokha of which Purana was the father of Narakasura was stated as Varaha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This excerpt](http://gdurl.com/WYWt) from the Brahma Purana describes how Narakarasura was born to Vishnu's incarnation Varaha and Bhumidevi goddess of the Earth after Varaha rescued the Pitris at Kokamukha:

> Chaya, the Earth conceived by lord Boar generated asura Naraka known also by the name Bhauma. Lord Vishnu gave him Pragjyotisha, the capital city of Kamarupa.

Comment: Is there any explanation of why he had Asura guna?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I posted a question on that already: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8123/36

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like it’s only in one place in the Brahma Puran. Could not find it listed anywhere else about Varaha being his father or even marrying Bhudevi - even that marriage is not in Brahma Puran.

Not sure where the story of Satyabhama killing Naraka comes from.

Comment: Satyabhama killing Naraka seems to be a folklore. All Puranas and Mahabharata are unanimous in the fact that Krishna killed Naraka with Sudarshana chakra.

Comment: @ms347 also mentions that Narakasura was born to Bhudevi and Varaha.          
 "When I was lifted by you, O Lord, in your boar incarnation, this son (Naraka) was born of me in consequence of your contact. So you gave that son to me and now he has been struck down by you."          
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128933.html