# Which one is the true version of the many Ramayanas out there?

Tags: ramayana, rama

In scripture its mentioned Ramayana happened in 24th Mahayuga and now we're living in 28th Mahayuga. Then why are different versions of the Ramayana mentioned? Or are all versions of Ramayana true which happened in different Kalpas?

Comment: Well this doesnt have an answer for my question. Can you check the difference in questions focus?

Comment: Your statement about yugas is unclear. If Ramayana happened in 28th Mahayuga, why does it depend on truthfulness of different versions? It answers to some part.The same Q is asked more than once with slight variations. instead of them, I linked the original. Same questions will not be repeated on the site because same answers will be or should be repeated again. Any new answers posted to the question should go to the original. That is how closure works. This answers your questions more I think. [Why are there different books on Ramayana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11986/5212)

Comment: Yes I understand the pattern how this site works. But thanks for this question! In scripture it is stated that Ramayana happened in 24th Treta Yuga, and now we're in 28th Mahayuga. So that's why I was confused why there are different versions and possibly I thought they could be in different Kalpas!

Comment: Yes, Kalpa Bheda is also one of the reasons. There are different versions in Padma Purana, Skanda Purana, Shiva Purana etc., but the basic story remains the same. There are only some basic differences. There are later versions as well as Kalpa Bhedas. Authentic version always remains Valmiki Ramayana as we are talking about this Manvantara and this Yuga.

Comment: @Arkaprabha This edit still makes the question duplicate of question "Why are there different books on Ramayana?" which I linked in other comment.. Still a duplicate.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padma Purana :

[image]

> "The legend of Shri Ram has been described in Shat-Koti Ramayanas, if
>   any differences are seen anywhere in those ancient stories, then wise
>   ones have suggested that it was because Shri Ram had performed his
>   pastimes diversely in different kalpas."

Ananda Ramayana :

[image]

> "Due to descent of Bhagvan Shri Ram again and again in different kalpas, infinite incarnations of Him have taken place. Among those infinite incarnations, there had also been differences at some place in His pastimes.

[image]

> The extremely amazing pastimes and valorous exploits of Bhagvan Shri Ram are spread across millions of Shastras. Sage Sukadeva is going to describe that infinite glory of Shri Ram in just two chapters and He summarizes the same in His single shloka.

So as you can see clearly the reason for so many Ramayanas, there evidently is no need to doubt which one is true, because the universe is not 100% predetermined. Things are randomized, but in a trajectory. A few distortions, alterations and dynamicity are ever-present in the hurricane, which is ultimately aimed at a single destination. Therefore all the Ramayanas are true, because they took place in different epochs.

Comment: This is the answer which gives satisfaction and is complete!

Comment: From this website, people should know hinduism is neither a religion or mythology.  Its universal truth and way of life

Comment: Hinduism is true in every aspect and fact of it. Hinduism is a derived term. Sanatan Dharma means eternal law. It is the way of nature. It is how nature works. Its nowhere a made-up system to follow. It itself is the universal system. The universe works through Dharma which we have received through the Gods, Munis and Rishis.

Comment: Please don't answer questions with duplicate votes. Answer the original one and you  will get more response. Correct thing is to close the question and answer the duplicate. If you think it is not a duplicate, then indicate the same in  a comment under the question and modify the question to show the change. Hope you follow it from next time.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: And btw I think I've answered it before it got any duplicate vote.