# Story of Lord Vishnu's sword Nandaka?

Tags: vishnu, scripture, puranas, weapon

According to [Annamayya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annamayya_(film)) Telugu Movie, Lord Venkateswara sends his sword *NANDAKA* to take birth as [Tallapaka Annamacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annamacharya) to compose Telugu songs for Him, at request of Padmavathi Devi. I know Sudarshana Chakra (discus), Gadha (mace) and conch but never heard about his sword.

- Do any Puranas mention about Vishnu's sword *Nandaka*?
- What's the story of Vishnu's sword *Nandaka*?
- Is it mentioned in any scriptures that Annamayya (Tallapaka Annamacharya) was an avatar of *Nandaka*?

Comment: I'm not sure about Annamacharya, but Sri Vaishnavas believe that Peyalwar, whom I discuss in this question, was an incarnation of Vishnu's Nandaka sword: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6867/36

Comment: Wiki states both were avatars of Nanadaka. Which scriptures says Peyalwar was avatar of Nanadaka? Is that scripture authentic?

Comment: Agni purana mention about Nandaka sword. But I do not know any scripture that say Annamayya is the incarnation of Nandaka.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Please post that as answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Agni Purana, Chapter 245](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12912/7/Chapter5_618-649p.pdf) describes the story of Nandaka sword as:

> Lord Brahma performed a sacrifice on the banks of celestial Ganges on the peaks of the Meru (mountain). When he was contemplating at the sacrifice he saw the demon Loha (that causes) obstruction. As he was thinking about that, **a great mighty form appeared from the fire** in front of him. He bowed down to the lord (Brahma) and the celestials greeted him with joy. **Lord Hari took the sword (called) Nandaka from the demon** as requested by the celestials. The lord seized it slowly and it became unsheathed. The sword was blue (in colour) with gem (studded) handle. Then the demon became (endowed with) hundred hands. That demon mad the celestials run away in the battlefield by means of the mace. the body of the demon was cut by lord Hari with the sword and (the parts of) the body fell on the earth and all of them became pieces of iron on account of their contact with the (sword) Nandaka. After having killed him lord Hari gave him a boon (saying) "Your holy body would become (the material) for weapons on the earth."

Hindi translation is trying to say that the great mighty form which appeared from the fire is known as Nandaka.[image]

**Update**

Now, I have found the good [translation](https://books.google.co.in/books?redir_esc=y&id=8pk3AQAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3AHf_y_hfJUZ8C&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Nandaka) of story which is:

> The god bowed down to Brahman and all the gods humbled themselves before him as well. The god Hari took the sword Nandaka from the hands of Fire-god, and the whole haven was jubilant.

Comment: Thanks! But i am interested in origin of Sword also.

Comment: @TheDestroyer When I am reading the hindi version of this story then "a great mighty form appeared from the fire" is known as Nandaka. So, Nandaka was originated from Lord Brahma yagna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer If you want the I can post Hindi translation also because I suppose English translation has messed.

Comment: @TheDestroyer edited and added the screen-shot.

Comment: Read that Hindi Story. I think English version will have this story too.

Comment: @TheDestroyer dspace has only one version of english translation. I think I have to look into some other website. What do you think?

Comment: Yes. IndianScriptures site doesn't have Agni Purana. English version is only available now on Dspace Westbengal.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes and that version is slightly different from Hindi translation.

Answer (score 1):

End of kali yuga Lord Vishnu comes in a white horse with Nandaka the sword and destroys the evil forces in a lightning manner.

> The Vishnu Purana says that Nandaka, "the pure sword" represents jnana
>   (knowledge), which is created from vidya (translated variously as
>   wisdom, knowledge, science, learning, scholarship, philosophy), its
>   sheath is avidya (ignorance or illusion). The Varaha Purana describes
>   it as the destroyer of ignorance. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nandaka#Symbolism)

Every ornament and weapon relates to the alwars in which Peyalwar is the sword Nandaka.

Comment: Please give reference of Vishnu Purana where it states Nanadakas as Jnana.

Comment: You copied the last two lines from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nandaka#Symbolism) and didn't mention the source. Plagiarism is not encouraged on SE sites.

Comment: For now i have fixed for post from next time own-wards remember to mention the source of information you provide in your answers.

Comment: @Ankit-- Please be clear in your English---what you have fixed  for post I don't understand. There is no word own-wards.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan This doesn't answer my question completely Though you answered my first question, you didn't cite Vishnu Purana. And you didn't answer my second part. Good for comment rather than answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan What Ankit did was to make clear that what you said was copied and pasted from Wikipedia, rather being your own words.