# Where is Amrit located at present?

Tags: chiranjivi, amrita

Is there any Amrit left at present ? Or All of it has been finished ? Where is currently located ?

Comment: By Shiva or Vishnu worship. As per mythology, during ocean churning he held Halahala poison that came up,  in throat with suspended animation. Vishnu/Mohini tricked the asuras, favoring devas in its distribution leaving behind no stock of the divine liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in External Universe it's present in Swarga Loka (Vishnu Padam).

Rig Veda 1:154:5.:

> “May I attain to that his well-loved mansion where men devoted to the Gods are happy. For there springs, close akin to the Wide-Strider, **the well of meath (nourishment)** in Viṣṇu's highest footstep”.

In the Internal Universe, it's a bit above Ajna Chakra.

Yoga-Kundalini Upanishad.:

> 67-69. (Kundalini) Pierces the Brahmagranthi formed of rajas and flashes at once like lightning at the mouth of Susumna. Then it goes up at once through Vishnugranthi to the heart. Then it goes up through Rudragranthi and above it to the middle of the eyebrows; having pierced this place (Ajna Chakra), it goes up to the Mandala (sphere) of the moon (Indu Chakra). **It dries up the moisture (amrita/soma) produced by the moon** in the Anahata (Indu/Moon) Chakra having sixteen petals.

Amrita/Soma is nothing but Moon/Soma only.

Shatapatha Brahmana Section 1.6.4.5.:

> The gods said, 'Nothing but Soma will satiate him: let us prepare Soma for him!' They prepared Soma for him. **Now this king Soma, the food of the gods, is no other than the moon.**

And the Yogi can drink that Amrita by doing Khechari Mudra.

Plus, as I have already mentioned in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57103/20968) and [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57172/20968) of mine, that the 3 steps of Vishnu on Earth, Atmosphere and Heaven in External Universe are equal to the passing of Kundalini Shakti through Brahma, Vishnu and Rudra Granthis in the Internal Universe. As, [Vishnu=Uma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/56389/20968).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 1):

Amrita means immortality; '*a*' - no, without - '*mrita*' - death. One who realises the eternal Self has Amrita. So Amrita is located in the Self. It is inexhaustible and is found within all beings. *Amritasiddhi*:

> **36.6. Immortality (Amrita) is a word for creation, **liberation** and life. The perfection (siddhi) of the three is taught here as the perfection of immortality (Amritasiddhi).**