# Is Vishnu the only major deity who is said to possess a navel in his moola form?

Tags: vishnu

one of Vishnu's famous names is पद्मनाभ (padmanabha)= "lotus-navelled".  Brahma is said to spring from this lotus - but why does Vishnu possess a navel in the first place?  the navel is where the umbilical cord attaches to human fetuses while in the mother's womb.

Comment: where is it said that other gods don’t hv navel?.. for instance, we hv a shaktipith where Devi’s navel fell down which means other god/goddesses too have navel…

Answer (score -3):

I guess by navel the op wants to ask about the lotus stalk coming out of the navel of Lord Vishnu in his moola form.

[image]

Well, its because according to both shrutis and smritis, Lord Vishnu is none other than the male form if Maa Uma. As i have discussed [in this answer of mine](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49785/20968). That's why the another name of Parmeshwara Shiva is Hari Ballavam means the husband/lover if Lord Hari.

Bhagawān Shiva and Lord Vishnu are Purusha and Prakritibin tattvam. They gave birth to the Hiranyagarbha (aka Lord Brahma). Where Lord
Brahma is called Hirayagarbha which means ‘Golden womb/foetus’. A stalk from Lord Vishnu’s navel supports a lotus on top of which Hirayagarbha remains joined (seated). What does this imply? A foetus when develops within the mother’s body, it always remains connected to the mother’s umbilical cord and through that cord it get’s its life sustaining materials. Lord Brahma is the golden-foetus who is connected to Lord Vishnu’s navel through an umbilical cord called as lotus-stalk. And Lord Vishnu being the sustainer of the universe (which is same as Hirayagarbha), he protects and sustains that Hirayagarbha on his lotus stalk. Madhu and Kaitabha demons attacked Hirayagarbha; Lord Vishnu killed those demons protecting Lord Brahma. On similar lines, whenever there is chaos within Hirayagarbha, Lord Vishnu takes incarnations and protects the worlds contained within Hiranyagarbha.

Sri Rudram of YajurVeda 5th Anuvaka states.:

> *नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च । **नमो मीढुष्टमाय** ... (Yajurveda 4.5).*
>
> *Salutations to Girisha, Shipivishta, **Midhustama.***

He is the giver of many things and thus the name **"Midhustama"** is given to Parameswara Shiva.

Lord Kartikeya in his Sri Rudram Bhasya (in Shiva Rahasya Itihāsa) says that Bhagawān Shiva is called Midhustama because he gave his seed to form Hiranyagarbha and thus as the originator of Lord Brahma.

> *रेतसः सेक्त्रे दिव्यहिरण्मयस्य च हरेर्गर्भे विधात्रे विधे:।।*
>
> ***who gave his Hiranyaretas (divine seed) in the womb of Hari and created Vidhata (Brahma).***

Again,

**Sri Shiva Purana 3:11:40.:**

> *प्रकृतिस्त्वं पुमान्रुद्रस्त्वयि वीर्य्यं समाहितम् । त्वन्नाभिपङ्कजाज्जातः पञ्च वक्त्रः पितामहः ॥ ४० ॥*
>
> ***40. You (Vishnu) are Prakṛti and Rudra is Puruṣa. The seed is deposited in you. The five-faced Brahmā was born of your umbilical lotus.***

Same thing is represented by **Sri Adi Shankaracharya** in his **Sri Shivananda Lahari** as follows.:

> *"Ardha vapusha baryatwam, Gonithwam sakkhitha..." (Shivananda Lahari Para-82).*
>
> ***"Lord Vishnu occupied half your body, Became transformed to be your wife (PARVATI), Became a boar to search for you (LINGA), Became your lady friend to serve the nectar (MOHINI)."***

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Lol. The burning smell. .. Music... Ooooooooo...